SSL in private network
My network contain one windows PC and dozens of embedded PCs running linux.
Customer requires that communication between PC and all endpoints will be secured.
In the endpoint I'm running python HTTP server:
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.check_hostname = False
context.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem', 'private.key')

server_address= ('10.0.0.2',1443)
httpd = HTTPServer (server_address, CustomHTTP)
httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever ()

Each endpoint has different IP (of course).
Should I create different certificate for each endpoint?

This question is very open to interpretation.   In the simplest case, if it should act like any typical HTTPS service on the web there are a few options.
Possibly the "best" option would be to get a valid HTTPS certificate for the server from a known CA whose CA cert is in the CA store of the clients.  You can do this even within a private network - either by purchasing a cert and having it verified through email, or by interacting with public DNS (and you can then use LetsEncrypt for free).   Of-course, for this to work, you need to use a valid domain name (even if it points to internal IP addresses)
An alternative would be to run your own CA and add your CA key to each of the clients.  This is not trivial, but is very doable with free tools (like easy-rsa - which I believe is/was associated with OpenVPN but is a stand-alone system that will work just fine for HTTPS).  Again, you will require some kind of name resolution for this to work.
The above 2 solutions assume its OK for the servers to trust the clients.   If this is not OK, then you need to step up the game.  There are at least 2 ways to do this -

Use something like easy-rsa to create a CA, and then create - and validate client side certificates.   This will require support from the web server.   In addition to the client validating the server, it also does the reverse.

Drop the idea of HTTPS, and instead set up VPN's between the devices (and enforce connectivity only through the VPN connections).  This will encrypt everything and may be more intuitive then setting up a CA.   You may be able to use something as simple/lightweight as Wireguard - otherwise OpenVPN can also do this.



It depends on customer's requirements.

If customer only wants protection from passive monitoring, then a generic bogus certificate without any verification is enough.

If customer wants protection from both passive monitoring and active attacks, then each endpoint must have its own certificate.


With many endpoints, you should create a local CA and use it to issue device certificates; then the clients will only need a single context.load_verify_locations("ca.crt") to be able to handle any endpoint. SmallStep (step-ca) and Easy-RSA are two commonly used tools for this.
(And of course, while check_hostname = False is okay on the server side, clients should not do that or it seriously weakens the protection from active attacks.)

I'd call these options "half-assed TLS" and "full TLS" respectively.
